# SumProduct Using Multiple Criteria Returning Too Much Data

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Although this question has been asked and answered, (Stack Overflow is where I learned how to implement SP), an issue has come up which I can't figure out.

I'm using SP to sum shipments within a pivot table using a product number (with wild-cards), and a specific date.  For instance, part numbers can be "AX10235-HP", "AX11135-HP", "AX10235-HP2", "AX10235-HPSPARE" or TP10101-IBM.  (There are a large variety of numbers.)

So in this case I want to sum the qty shipments of "AX???35-HP".  I wish to sum just the first 2 parts in my short list.  However, the command used causes all the parts to sum except the *-IBM number; as if there was a wild-card at the end of the number.  In other words `"AX???35-HP"` is the same as `"AX???35-HP*"`.  I've tried wrapping the value in quotes but it takes uses the quotes literally so fails.

This is the function

```
SUMPRODUCT((S_PART_DATA)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A6,S_PART_RANGE))*(S_PART_DATES=T$4)))
```

- `S_PART_DATA` array of Shipments,
- `S_PART_RANGE` array of list of part numbers,
- `S_PART_DATES` array of Dates shipments were made

Answer (score 0):

It works the way you describe because `SEARCH` function finds $A6 **within** other text, hence it may not be an exact match - better to use `SUMIFS` function like this:

`=SUMIFS(S_PART_DATA,S_PART_RANGE,$A6,S_PART_DATES,T$4)`

Assuming all named ranges are the same size and A6 contains the value **AX???35-HP**

If that doesn't work try this version

`=SUMPRODUCT(S_PART_DATA*ISNUMBER(SEARCH("^"&$A6&"^","^"&S_PART_RANGE&"^"))*(S_PART_DATES=T$4))`

concatenating the ^ values means you will [probably] only get exact matches

Comment: Thank you Barry, however, I get a #VALUE! error with this solution.  Can you do an array summation with SUMIF(s)?  The data to be summed is in a large pivot table.

Comment: I don't know if it's a problem because of the pivot table or how the named ranges are defined - I suggested another solution closer to your original

Comment: Congratulations!  that last equation with the carats worked!  I tried with and without wildcards.